# Paypal Sandbox ExpressCheckout NVP not creating transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I'm trying to integrate PayPal Classic API NVP to our website but I'm having issues with the `SetExpressCheckout` API call.

I'm using the `useraction=commit` parameter for the payer to confirm the sale directly at PayPal.

My issue is after "Pay now" is clicked, PayPal redirects to the URL I send as `RETURNURL` but I don't see the transaction on the sandbox account or by using `TransactionSearch`.

These are the parameters I send for checkout:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
EMAIL=payerEmail
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
RETURNURL=myReturnUrl
CANCELURL=myCancelUrl
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=30.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=30.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=myCustomId
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=30.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=myProduct
```

After payment, PayPal redirects to

```
myReturnUrl?token={Token}&PayerID={PayerId}
```

Comment: Give more information about how exactly you use the API, code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. The transaction is set, but you need to complete it using the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` api operation.

More information and an example here: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/dotnet?success=true&token=EC-7BD474648D4932937&PayerID=WNW7LMW2UXQJG

Comment: Yes, you are right, reading this [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/), seems that using the `useraction=commit` param is not enough to finalize payment as I thought so.